# Kotlin Multiplatform expect/actual on Interface

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

trying kotlin multiplatform with compose, project bootstrap from [Kotlin Multiplatform Wizard](https://kmp.jetbrains.com/?_ga=2.27414332.1643457420.1701297071-477856113.1700310367&_gac=1.216172260.1700747370.CjwKCAiAjfyqBhAsEiwA-UdzJOJEoW-iLETj6Pv6n4hGwyOiT5v78z-ctY8ExV61_RsoRnQ2O1vdgxoC2dIQAvD_BwE&_gl=1*1e3jx3j*_ga*NDc3ODU2MTEzLjE3MDAzMTAzNjc.*_ga_9J976DJZ68*MTcwMTM3MzY1MC4xMC4wLjE3MDEzNzM2NTEuNTkuMC4w), as indicate in [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/kotlin-multiplatform-dev/compose-multiplatform-create-first-app.html)

and strugle with expect and actual, basicaly i need to get Accelerometer, so i create an interface like i have seen on some articles

`composeApp/src/commonMain/kotlin/Accelerometer.kt`

```
expect interface Accelerometer {
    fun startListening(callback: (Float, Float, Float) -> Unit)
    fun stopListening()
}
```

`android` and `ios` methods are empty for now, cant even get it to work.....
`composeApp/src/androidMain/kotlin/Accelerometer.android.kt`

```
actual class AccelerometerAndroid : Accelerometer { 
    actual override fun startListening(callback: (Float, Float, Float) -> Unit) {}  
    actual override fun stopListening() {}
}
```

`composeApp/src/androidMain/kotlin/Accelerometer.ios.kt`

```
actual class AccelerometerIOS : Accelerometer {    
    actual override fun startListening(callback: (Float, Float, Float) -> Unit) {}  
    actual override fun stopListening() {}
}
```

my file structure

```
├── composeApp
│   └── src
│       ├── androidMain
│       ├── commonMain
│       └── iosMain
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
└── iosApp
    ├── Configuration
    ├── iosApp
    │   ├── Assets.xcassets
    │   └── Preview\ Content
    └── iosApp.xcodeproj
        └── project.xcworkspace
```

and get error:
Actual class `AccelerometerAndroid` has no corresponding expected declaration

and Android Studio `enter code here`fix hint are:
`create expected class in common module long.module.name.composeApp.commonMain`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing regular inheritance with the `expect`/`actual` mechanism.

The `expect`/`actual` mechanism only works with identical declarations: an `expect class` must have an `actual class` equivalent. Also, note that expected classes are actually not a stable part of Kotlin Multiplatform, they are still experimental. Usually you can do what you need with `expect fun`/`actual fun`.

This is actually your case here, you don't need expect/actual on types. Just use a regular interface, and regular classes implementing the interface in your platform specific modules. Then, use an `expect`/`actual` function to get an instance of your interface (which will be different between platforms):

Common:

```kotlin
interface Accelerometer {
    fun startListening(callback: (Float, Float, Float) -> Unit)
    fun stopListening()
}

expect fun createAccelerometer(): Accelerometer
```

Android:

```kotlin
private class AndroidAccelerometer : Accelerometer { 
    override fun startListening(callback: (Float, Float, Float) -> Unit) {
        // android implementation
    }  
    override fun stopListening() {
        // android implementation
    }
}

actual fun createAccelerometer(): Accelerometer = AndroidAccelerometer()
```

iOS:

```kotlin
private class IOSAccelerometer : Accelerometer { 
    override fun startListening(callback: (Float, Float, Float) -> Unit) {
        // iOS implementation
    }  
    override fun stopListening() {
        // iOS implementation
    }
}

actual fun createAccelerometer(): Accelerometer = IOSAccelerometer()
```

Comment: yeah !! got it, will test soon. And where is the docs? im find too hard to found the docs about kmp

Comment: The first Google search result for "Kotlin expect actual" gives you exactly what I described: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-expect-actual.html#interfaces-with-expected-and-actual-functions